# Pass URL from Google Script to HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having an issue passing a URL that I want the user to go to when they click a button on my sidebar.

```
  <body>
      <p class="header">First we need to Authorize.</p>
    <button class="center waves-effect waves-light btn" id="btn">Authorize</button>

     <script>
        document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",authorize);
 
        function authorize(){
          google.script.run.authorizeSidebar();

        }
 </script>
  </body>
```

My code on GS is:

```
function authorizeSidebar(){
var Authservice = getAuthorization();
    var authorizationUrl = Authservice.getAuthorizationUrl();
    //Logger.log(authorizationUrl);
 
 }
```

I'm able to output the URL I need on the second function, but I'm having a hard time passing it from the GS file to the HTML file for the user to click on.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callback function in [`.withSuccessHandler()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) would receive the url returned by the server function:

#### Client side:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",authorize);

function callbackReceiver(url){//☎️
  alert(url);
}


function authorize(){
   google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(callbackReceiver)
    .authorizeSidebar();
}
</script>
```

#### Server side:

```
function authorizeSidebar(){
  return getAuthorization()
        .getAuthorizationUrl();   
}
```